# Issue with EditText in Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have one `ListView`, which has custom adapter (it saves Strings). Each `row` contains one `EditText`.

### Activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fdf7e9"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bar" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/editAccount"
                android:textColor="#fffdf8eb" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.72"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listPhoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fdf7e9"
            android:cacheColorHint="#fdf7e9"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="15dip"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="false" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBtns"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.13"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/updateAccount"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/menu_quit_account" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelEditAccount"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### ROW Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fffdf7e9"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumberDescript"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="č. 1 : "
        android:textColor="#ad865d"
        android:width="50dip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumberText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/phoneNumberDescript"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ff3c2415" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/deletePhoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/delete" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numberId"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### What I want:

If I click on the EditText in the ListView, I want to put up the whole layout to see what I am writing into it.

### Issue:

After the click it pushes up the whole layout, until I write the first letter into the EditText or I click again on the focused EditText. After that the layout scrolls down, but it doesn't loose the focus, because I can continue to write the input, but i can't see what I am writing, because it is hided by the softkeyboard.

The ListView has also Header and Footer, which have also EditTextes. With these EditTextes the issue is the same: **after the first letter or after repeated click on it the Layout scrolls back to normal position.**

---

In the Manifest I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

I tried also `numbersListView.setItemsCanFocus(true)`

Comment: Have you got any answer or solutions?